# Android Device Monitor Doesn't Respond

Tags: unity-game-engine, android-device-monitor, info-plist

I want to debug my game with Android Device Monitor but monitor app doesn't response any mouse clicks. I tried so many things but nothing helps. Uncommented info plist -vm Java frameworks but the result is same. How can fix it ? Any help appreciated.

Comment: Its been deprecated in Android Studio 3.1 and removed from Android Studio 3.2. Check the link for more help. https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/monitor

Comment: Thanks for your answer so I cannot debug any more with ADM

Comment: Yeah as per the docs you cant but you can have other option. Mark this answer correct please.